# To concatenate values in different columns separated by symbol("-") to 1 column

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

In column A  cell contains values in the format: GL-A/123/1-data1,in column B value is 
PL1-B/143/1-data2,so on it follows the same format in column c and columnD.

I need it  to be formated in such a way that, in Column E it should be: 
A/123/1-data1;B/143/1-data2

Comment: You can use `CONCATENATE()` for this.

Comment: But i want it to be concatenated in the format specified as A/123/1-data1;B/143/1-data2

Comment: Check out the functions `InStr`, `InStrRev`, `Left`, `Right`, `Mid` and maybe `Split`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A formula that will work, in E1 and copy down.:

```
=CONCATENATE(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1)),";",MID(B1,FIND("-",B1)+1,LEN(B1)))
```

[image]

Comment: @user6124516 please mark as correct, it is something only you can do.  Click the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Can this logic be applied for a range of values?

Comment: If i have values ranging from A1 to AA1

Answer (score 2):

```
=CONCATENATE(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1)),";",MID(B1,FIND("-",B1)+1,LEN(B1)))
```